# UICollectionViewCell: can I know exactly when the cell appears and disappears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I need to do some animation in a `UICollectionViewCell`, and I want to start the animation when the cell appears and stop/pause it when it disappears.

I guess there's no single method that tells me exactly what I want? I'm looking at:

**`collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`**  I guess this isn't the place when the cell appears and visible, because it gets called even in `viewDidLoad` of my view controller.

**`layoutSubviews`**  and **`didMoveToSuperview`** The problem is that, `UICollectionView` could pre-loads a cell offscreen, in this case these two won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: collectionview has it's own delegate willdisplayCell & endDIsplayCell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell  forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: `didEndDisplayingCell` refers to the cell being removed from the collection view. From the Apple docs: "Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the collection view."

Comment: `didEndDisplayingCell` does tell the delegate that specified cell was removed from collection view but if required it may get reused if called by collection view using `dequeueReusableCell`